# Connect a server to a wireless router

Tags: windows-server-2003, wifi

My Windows 2003 server is connected via lan cable to a wireless router, the other computers are connected via wireless access to the router. How can I use this server as a file server, so that the computers connected to the wireless router can access it.

Comment: By default, the LAN ports on your access point would be on the same network as your wireless hosts.  Isn't this the case?  What kind/model of access point are we talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without details, but If the router does not bridge the wireless network with the physical network, you may need to look for an option to do this.  Otherwise, if they are in the same subnet, you should just be able to access the file server by IP.

Comment: Thanks, I will look for this option. If i find the solution, I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a cheap Linksys/Dlink/Cisco wireless router, then I don't see the issue. You should be able to set up the file server and other clients on the network would see it as they're on the same network as you.

If, on the other hand, you're using a Sonicwall or some other wireless router that separates the wireless and wired networks by default, you're going to have some work to do. :)

Comment: As an aside, I personally prefer the ones that separate the two networks. It's a wireless 'router' after all; your subnets should be different. It allows you to identify your (potentially riskier) wireless clients easily.